# How to solve Indent In TinyMCE only First line of paragraph

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor

I want to ask about tiny mce, before I think to ask at tinymce forum but forum are closed now, when I try to register, I have a problem with indent on tiny mce editor plugins, when I write some paragraph in tiny mce and I add indent on first line result is other line are going indent to..how to solve this problem, this is my illustration..

**This is My tinyMCE**

[image]

**This is result I hope**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is not indenting but rather a hanging indent.  You can accomplish this with some CSS such as:

```
p.hangingIndent { 
  text-indent: -28px;
  padding-left: 28px;
}
```

You then apply the appropriate class to the paragraph that needs the hanging indent.  TinyMCE has several ways you can apply CSS to a block element such as a paragraph.

Comment: The documentation provides several ways to get that done:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/